# How to use leaflet markerclusterGroup?

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I want to create a leaflet marker cluster group and I want to add all the markers, and for that I have written the below-mentioned code. But I am getting the error `TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a constructor`

I am not getting that there is an error in the scripting or in the code that I have written

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/MarkerCluster.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js'></script>
```

```js
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addLayer(L.marker(getRandomLatLng(map)));
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You do not need to include both `leaflet.markercluster.js` and `leaflet.markercluster-src.js`; you just need one of them.

In the `head` section of your HTML, include the following:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, in your JavaScript, create a marker cluster group:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

create some markers:

```
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(0, 0));
```

add the markers to the cluster group:

```
markers.addLayer(marker);
```

and finally add the cluster group to the map:

```
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fimaxap/2/edit?html,js,output) to see a working example.

Comment: why do you include two CSS files for markers cluster lib.?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Not entirely sure but it seems to work without the MarkerCluster.css import as well.

Answer (score 7):

Here you have a simple working example with Open Street Maps, just try it by running this snippet.

As you may see we need to include two CSS files from `markercluster`, namely `MarkerCluster.css` and `MarkerCluster.Default.css`. We must include the CSS and JS files from `markercluster` only after the inclusion of the leaflet files.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([38, -8], 7)

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  const marker = L.marker([
    getRandom(37, 39), 
    getRandom(-9.5, -6.5)
  ])
  markers.addLayer(marker)
}
map.addLayer(markers);

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
#map {height: 400px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.5.0/MarkerCluster.Default.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```